# Angular input pattern validation not working

Tags: angular

Can someone explain to me why my `ngIf` is not working when it should be activating when the pattern error occurs?

```html
<div>
   <form #myForm="ngForm">
      <h1>Angular Calculator</h1>

      <h4>Sum:</h4>
      <input [(ngModel)]='add1' type="text" name="add1" size="5" pattern="^(0-9)*(/.(0-9)+)?$" required> +
      <input [(ngModel)]='add2' type="text" name="add2" size="5" pattern="^(0-9)*(/.(0-9)+)?$" required>

      <p *ngIf="add1?.errors?.pattern">
         Only numeric characters allowed</p>
      <p *ngIf="add2?.errors?.pattern">
         Only numeric characters allowed</p>
      &nbsp;
      <button (click)='CalcAdd()'>
         =
      </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'myForm' object for showing the error messages. I have changed in the code ngIf condition. see the working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyjj13?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Here is the changed code.

```
  <div>
  <form #myForm="ngForm">
  <h1>Angular Calculator</h1>

  <h4>Sum:</h4>
  <input [(ngModel)]='add1' type="text" id="add1" name="add1" size="5" pattern="^(0-9)*(/.(0-9)+)?$"   required/> + <input [(ngModel)]='add2' type="text" name="add2"  size="5" pattern="^(0-9)*(/.(0-9)+)?$" required>

  <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.add1?.errors?.pattern">
      Only numeric characters allowed</p>
  <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.add2?.errors?.pattern">
      Only numeric characters allowed</p>
  &nbsp;
  <button (click)='CalcAdd()'>
    =
  </button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The error shows even if I enter in a valid character - is there something wrong with my pattern?

Comment: do you want only numeric in the textbox or decimal values?

Comment: Either numeric or decimals should be valid.

Comment: try to use this pattern [0-9\.]+$ and I have updated the code, which only accepts numeric.

Comment: That works! Thank you! If it's alright I have one more question, how would I add to the ngIF to disable the button when the error occurs?

Comment: use this code on button : [disabled]="!myForm.valid" . I also added disabled attribute on button, please check sample application.

Comment: When I add it to my application the button stays permanently disabled. But I can see that it seems to work on your sample application.

Comment: check 'myForm' object is defined. otherwise share your form html code or screenshot.

Comment: I think I know the reason, I have other input boxes as well for subtracting, multiplying etc. The code [disabled]="!myForm.valid" seems to apply to the entire form - is there any way to isolate it to just the add1/add2 values?

Comment: then use this : [disabled]="!(!(myForm.controls.add1?.errors) && !(myForm.controls.add2?.errors))" and also updated the code. please check